# Questions about Rsnapshot - user permissions, deletion and hardlinks

Tags: backup, rsnapshot

1. Does Rsnapshot need root permissions on remote server side? I'm using a common user.

   ```
   backup   commonuser@remoteserver:/directory   directory/
   ```

   I'd like to backup some folders like `/home`, `/opt`, `/etc` and others, but it's not copying all files. My original `/home` (remote server) has 35GB but rsnapshot only copied 2.6GB.
2. If I delete a file in my backup folders (e.g. alpha.0), does the file get deleted on remote server side too?
3. Since rsnapshot works with hardlinks, where are the original files?

**EDIT:**
Now my command gives me this:

`rsnapshot -v -c /usr/local/etc/rsnapshot-ovh.conf alpha`:

> echo 49721 > /var/run/rsnapshot.pid /bin/rm -rf /rsnap_ovh/alpha.5/ mv
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.4/ /rsnap_ovh/alpha.5/ mv /rsnap_ovh/alpha.3/
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.4/ mv /rsnap_ovh/alpha.2/ /rsnap_ovh/alpha.3/ mv
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.1/ /rsnap_ovh/alpha.2/ /bin/cp -al /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.1 cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/home/home/zimbra_backup/zimbra/data/ldap/state/run/ldapi
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/home/home/zimbra_backup/zimbra/data/clamav/clamav.sock
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/home/home/zimbra_backup/zimbra/data/tmp/amavisd-zmq.sock
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/home/home/zimbra_backup/zimbra/data/amavisd/amavisd.sock
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/home/home/zimbra_backup/zimbra/data/sasl2/state/mux
>   is a socket (not copied). cp: /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/run/run/udev/control
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/run/run/dbus/system_bus_socket is a socket (not
>   copied). cp: /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/run/run/abrt/abrt.socket is a socket
>   (not copied). cp: /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/run/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock is a
>   socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/run/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 is a socket (not
>   copied). cp: /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/run/run/systemd/private is a socket
>   (not copied). cp: /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/run/run/systemd/journal/stdout is
>   a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/run/run/systemd/journal/socket is a socket (not
>   copied). cp: /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/run/run/systemd/notify is a socket
>   (not copied). cp: /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/run/run/systemd/cgroups-agent is
>   a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/run/run/systemd/shutdownd is a socket (not copied).
>   cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/trace
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/proxymap
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/defer
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/tlsmgr
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/rewrite
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/scache
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/tlsproxy
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/cyrus
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/anvil
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/discard
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/lmtp
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/uucp
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/maildrop
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/smtpd
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/old-cyrus
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/smtp
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/local
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/relay
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/dnsblog
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/bounce
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/virtual
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/scan
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/ifmail
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/retry
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/bsmtp
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/smtp-amavis
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/verify
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/private/error
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/public/pickup
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/public/cleanup
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/public/qmgr
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/public/flush
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/postfix/spool/public/showq
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/tmp/amavisd-zmq.sock
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/sasl2/state/mux
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/clamav/clamav.sock
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/ldap/state/run/ldapi
>   is a socket (not copied). cp:
>   /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups/zimbra_backup/data/amavisd/amavisd.sock
>   is a socket (not copied). /usr/local/bin/rsync -ptog --delete
>   --numeric-ids --relative \
>       --delete-excluded --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh root@remoteserver:/backups \
>       /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- rsnapshot encountered an error! The program was invoked with these
>   options: /usr/local/bin/rsnapshot -v -c
>   /usr/local/etc/rsnapshot-ovh.conf alpha
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- ERROR: /usr/local/bin/rsync returned 1 while processing
>   root@remoteserver:/backups touch /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/ rm -f
>   /var/run/rsnapshot.pid

Comment: Your example shows backing up of `/directory`. If you want to backup `/home`, `/opt`, and `/etc` please show the actual lines. While you're editing your question please include the definition for `rsync_short_args` and `rsync_long_args`.

Comment: My rsync_short_args and rsync_long_args are commented. 
I added my rsnapshot -t output.

Answer (score 2):

You normally want to run `rsnapshot` as `root` user and also copy the files as `root` on the remote side. Otherwise all user and group ownerships would be set to the user you are using to connect to the remote side, which will render your backup to useless.
To check why not all data was copied, look into the logs which by default is the system log or if you have configured a logfile you have to consult that one. In doubt which log mechanism is enabled, check your configuration file.
If you run the `cronjob` as common user, that might be the cause as the user might not have the permission to copy all the data.

You shouldn't touch the backup folders `rsnapshot` is creating. `rsnapshot` will copy things from the source as it is and will create a new folder which will reflect the contents of the source at a given time. Depending on your retention policy, a deleted folder in the source will vanish over time in your backup.

Hardlinks are different directory entries pointing to the same `inode`. It is not possible to determine which directory entry was the *original*. It is also possible that the first directory entry pointing to a file was deleted a long time ago, but other directory entries are still pointing/referencing this file.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply.
I noticed this in my log: Jul  9 09:04:09 rsnapshot rsnapshot[9615]: /usr/local/bin/rsnapshot -c /usr/local/etc/rsnapshot-ovh.conf alpha: ERROR: /usr/local/bin/rsnapshot -c /usr/local/etc/rsnapshot-ovh.conf alpha: completed, but with some errors

I'm running rsnapshot as root and connecting to root@remoteserver, but it's still giving me incomplete backups. 
root@rsnapshot:/var/log # du -lhs /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups
 56G    /rsnap_ovh/alpha.0/backups/backups
Remote server: 
du -lhs /backups
82G     /backups

Comment: Try to run `rsnapshot` with `-v` flag and/or increase the verbosity within your config file.

Comment: It says some files are sockets and it won't copy them. I edited my question.